# Parallel Sort O(log n)

Tags: sorting, parallel-processing

Does anyone know a pseudo code for any parallel algorithm that can sort N elements with a time complexity of O(log n)?

I think quicksort and selection sort are the best candidates for this task, but as far as I know, their complexity is O(n log n).

Regards,

Comment: Parallelism does not change the complexity of an algorithm unless one assume an infinite number of core (or a number of core that scale with the number of item). The later assumption is completely realistic but often done in university teaching courses (see the PRAM model). The best sort using comparison operates in `O(n log n)`. This is proven. The best sort not using comparison (eg. radix sort) operates in `O(n)` (one need at least to read the input).

Comment: *"their complexity is O(n log n)"* No. Both runs in `O(n²)` though this is improbable for quick-sort to run in `O(n²)` unless for some rare pathological inputs. Merge sort runs in `O(n log n)`. It can also be parallelised quite efficiently (using a bitonic mergesort).

Comment: You can find information like that on Wikipedia freely and easily. I strongly encourage you to do that.